# Problem with quotes in String in OutputStream in Java

Tags: java, json, post, backend, outputstream

I have the following problem: the request body does not display a string if there are quotes or curly braces in the string.

For example, in this code

```
HttpContext context = server.createContext("/api/hello", (exchange -> {
    if ("POST".equals(exchange.getRequestMethod())){
        
        ...
        
        OutputStream output = exchange.getResponseBody();
        output.write("{\"number\":12}".getBytes());
        output.flush();
    } else {
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(405, -1);
    }
}));
```

string `"{\"number\":12}"` does not display. At the same time if I change it to string `"flower"` (without quotes or curly braces), then it displays normally. How to display a string like `"{\"number\":12}"` ? I need it to display JSON in the response body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code snippet sends a successful response when submitting `POST http://localhost:8383/api/hello`:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8383), 100);
        server.createContext("/api/hello", (exchange -> {
            System.out.println("Got POST request" + exchange.getRequestURI());
            if ("POST".equals(exchange.getRequestMethod())){

                String json = "{\"message\": \"Hello World!\"}";

                exchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, json.length());

                OutputStream output = exchange.getResponseBody();
                output.write(json.getBytes());
                output.flush();
            } else {
                exchange.sendResponseHeaders(405, -1);
            }
        }));

        server.start();
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "message": "Hello World!"
}
```

It seems, the issue is not with the string contents of the response but with making a call to `sendResponseHeaders` followed by writing to the output stream:

```
exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, json.length());
```

Setting of `Content-Type` HTTP header is optional.

Comment: Thank you, Alex, it works! :). Indeed, code row `exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, json.length());` turned out to be necessary to display the JSON response. Row `exchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/json");` does display more beautiful.

Comment: For the reader, I want to note that this line `json` (which is used like `json.length()`, for example) must be exactly the line that you are printing.